# Batch file to open specific folders in specific window position

Tags: batch-file, explorer

I have a batch file that opens 3 specific folders, but I want the batch file, if possible, to show the windows side by side.

Comment: What you mean with side by side?. And why not use VBS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using VBS(Visual Basic Scripting) for this job.

You can easily arrange the open windows in common ways like: Cascade, TileHorizontally, TileVertically, etc.

For example, the following script will open three specific folders and then tile horizontally the open windows on screen:

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

shell.Open "path_folder1"
shell.Open "path_folder2"
shell.Open "path_folder3"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

shell.TileHorizontally
```

Of course, you can also open the folders from the batch and then call a .vbs script to arrange the windows.

**EDIT:**

To arrange in the screen only the specific opened windows, we can first minimize all present windows, then do the job:

```
Dim shell
Set shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

shell.MinimizeAll

shell.Open "path_folder1"
shell.Open "path_folder2"
shell.Open "path_folder3"

Wscript.Sleep 1000

shell.TileHorizontally
```

However, if you want to keep old windows active in the same position they was before and at the same time to arrange ONLY new windows, i don't have a solution right now.

Comment: The VB opens the windows, but doesn't tile them.

Comment: It actually seems to tile all the open windows except for the ones that the script opens.

Comment: BWT, i added a `Wscript.Sleep 1000` in the first script, you may try that too if you want to keep all the windows previously opened and the new ones in screen.

Comment: I'm building these in Visual Studio 2013 as a VB Console Application and it's telling me "Wscript is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to it's protection level." How do I fix this?

Comment: Is not VB, it is VBS (Visual Basic Scripting), its a scripting language modeled on Visual Basic, is executed by a intepreter in a host enviroment like the  Windows Script Host, that is installed by default in every desktop release of Windows. Its used for system administration (and etc.), but now PowerShell is more popular.

Comment: Just create a new .txt file, put the code in it, and rename it to .vbs, you dont need VS2013 for this. Is almost as simpe as writing a batch file